# Unable to format a question, two syntax issues

Tags: support, formatting

I wrote the following response
[Proving logic statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988566/proving-logic-statements/988884#988884), but am running into multiple issues formatting it the way I would like.
About half the syntaxes I try from 
https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help
are not working for me.

, +, *, - for bullet points, none work
4 leading spaces for indent on the sample proof.  Some of the blockquote styles would be overkill because it's an algebra proof tip, not a logic proof.

double space at end of line for newline is broken, but < br > seems to work well.

Is the bug tag appropriate for this metaquestion?

Comment: Someone posted this which is certainly useful, even though not exact what I'm looking for.  Then deleted it, so I'm reposting.http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: If your complaint is that two spaces for line break do not work *when in math mode*, then it is how it is supposed to work. But you can do this `$(x+1)^2-x^2=\\2x+1$` which renders as $(x+1)^2-x^2=\\2x+1$. (Caution: This works in MathJax, but not in LaTeX.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this post I am just testing things which your wrote do not work. You can click on *edit* below to see the source code.

If I put here two spaces
I get new line.

The same effect
can be obtained using `<br>`.

If I need newline in math mode, I have to do it differently:
$(x+1)^2-x^2=\\2x+1$

Sometimes it my be better to use align environment
$\begin{align}
(x+1)^2-x^2&=(x^2+2x+1)-x^2\\
&=2x+1
\end{align}$

```
4 space indentation
for preformated text
which may include some mathematical symbols
$x^2+y^2=z^2$
they are not rendered using MathJax
```

Now I try to start a list (I put an empty line before it):

- Item 1: $x+y=z$
- Item 2: $y+z=x$
- Item 3: What about including only math?
- $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$

For some bizarre reason if I want to use preformatted text again, I cannot do so immediately after the list.

```
4 space indentation
for preformated text
which may include some mathematical symbols
$x^2+y^2=z^2$
they are not rendered using MathJax
```

Comment: I have edited the post, thanks for pointing this out.
I posted the answer mainly in the hope that OP will be able to point out what exactly the problem is or make some little experiments to show the problem. Since my guess was that the OP might have tried using markdown in math mode, I have included some examples of mathematics which is written on several lines.